# Выпадающий textfield по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: ios, swift

Как можно сделать выпадающий textfield по нажатии на кнопку (checkbox) Может есть какой-то pod, который я не могу нагуглить или все же это делается элементарно)

Примеры по которым я должен придерживаться

1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

"Выпадающий" textfield Вы можете легко сделать с помощью UIStackView. Пример для кнопки, но подойдет для объяснения:

1 Добавьте нужный элемент в `UIStackView`

2 Установите ему нужную высоту и для этой `constraint` и задайте приоритет 999

3 При изменении `isHidden` textfield будет выпадать/скрываться

4 Можно анимировать

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.5,
    animations: {
        self.someButton.isHidden.toggle()
        self.buttonsContainerStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Пример на GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/UIStackViewExamples/tree/master)